# php htaccess rewrite failed

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, spl-autoload-register

i set up a php mvc framework, this is my htaccess file. it works find, however, after i go back to the index page, it can not find the default platform, controller and method, and the other links work find, just the index page. i try to unset the default platform, controller and method after get the the value, but still not working

```
    RewriteEngine on
    Options -Indexes
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
    #RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z_-]*)?/?([a-zA-Z_-]*)$ index.php?platform=$1&controller=$2&action=$3 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z_-]*)?/?([a-zA-Z_-]*)/?([0-9]*)$ index.php?platform=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&id=$4 [NC,L]
```

in my controller, the url is working, could pass the parameter and open the link.
my  url in the browser: blog.com/admin/products/list

```
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    echo  'i am del';
    echo 'my id is :'.$id;
    echo '<br>';
    echo "<a href='/'>index</a>";
    echo '<br>';
    echo "<a href='/admin/products/list'>List</a>";
```

but when i click index,(blog.com), the message show up:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class '\Controller\Controller' not found in; if ok, it should be like '\Controller**Admin****ProductsController****list**'
the default platform and controller and method is gone;
this is my php file:

```
     private static function initRoutes()
        {
            //unset($p);
            $p = $_GET['platform'] ?? "Admin";
            $c = $_GET['controller'] ?? "Products";
            $a = $_GET['action'] ?? "list";
            $p = ucfirst(strtolower($p));
            $c = ucfirst(strtolower($c));        
            $a = strtolower($a);            
            define('PLATFROM_NAME', $p);   
            define('CONTROLLER_NAME', $c);  
            define('ACTION_NAME', $a);      
            define('__URL__', CONTROLLER_PATH . $p . DS);  
            define('__VIEW__', VIEW_PATH . $p . DS);     //view path

        }
```

load the class:

```
    private static function initAutoLoad()
        {
            spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {[enter image description here][1]
                $namespace = dirname($class_name);   
                $class_name = basename($class_name); 
                if (in_array($namespace, array('Core', 'Lib')))   
                    $path = FRAMEWORK_PATH . $namespace . DS . $class_name . '.class.php';
                elseif ($namespace == 'Model')     
                    $path = MODEL_PATH . $class_name . '.class.php';
                elseif ($namespace == 'Traits')    
                    $path = TRAITS_PATH . $class_name . '.class.php';
                else   
                    $path = CONTROLLER_PATH . PLATFROM_NAME . DS . $class_name . '.class.php';
                if (file_exists($path) && is_file($path))
                    require $path;
            });
        }
```

the object:

```
    private static function initDispatch()
        {
            $controller_name = '\Controller\\' . PLATFROM_NAME . '\\' . CONTROLLER_NAME . 'Controller';    
            $action_name = ACTION_NAME . 'Action';    
            $obj = new $controller_name();
            $obj->$action_name();
        }
```

[url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX0e4.png)

Comment: learn to use Composer's included autoloader

Answer (score 0):

`initAutoLoad` and the `.htaccess`-file are irrelevant:

- The error tells me that `initDispatch` is not creating the correct
  classname (this comes before the autoloading)
- None of the rewrite rules in
  the htaccess file match "/" and it is probably defaulting to calling the index file without rewrite

`\Controller\\Controller` is the class name this tells me that both `PLATFROM_NAME` and `CONTROLLER_NAME` are empty.

`initRoutes` defines these 2 variables. The only explaination I can think of:

`initDispatch` is called before `initRoutes`

Install XDebug and set a breakpoint into `initRoutes` is the quickest way to find out.